# Pie Chart with Highchatrs

Tags: jquery, highcharts

My array is like this :

`[{"label":"1","y":0,"custom":"1 : 0"},{"label":"3","y":3,"custom":"3 : 3"}]`

And My jQuery code for draw chart is as below :

```
function generateGraph(value) {
    $('#loadingmessage').show();
    que_id = $(value).attr('data-id');
    que_type = $(value).attr('data-que-type');
    que_txt = $(value).parent('h4').find('.que_txt').text();

    var jsonData =
            $.ajax({
        url: "ajax.php?action=getGraphDetails",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            "que_id": que_id,
            "que_type": que_type,
        },
        async: false
    }).responseText;
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonData);
    var dataXAxis = [];
    var dataYAxis = [];
    var length = 0;
    length = obj.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        dataXAxis.push(obj[i].label);
        dataYAxis.push(obj[i].y);
    }

    $('#curve_chart').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: que_txt,
            x: -20 //center
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: dataXAxis
        },
        yAxis: {
            reversed: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            useHTML: true,
            shared: true
        },
        series: [{
                name: dataXAxis,
                data: dataYAxis,
                color: '#FF0000'
            }]
    });
}
```

Now my questions is set dataXaxis as name of piechart and dataYaxis as y of pie chart.

Please help me for the same.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please please answer of my question.
If anyone is available.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update** As per comment below , you need label (your series data labels) and value.try using following:

```
       dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.y}',

            }
```

see [**Updated fiddle as per your comment**](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/ng1kvmxh/36/)

use following code :
I created an array named dataPie and pushed your json data into that . in highcharts I called that variable.

```
 var dataPie =[];
var abc = [{"label":"1","y":2,"custom":"1 : 0"},   {"label":"3","y":3,"custom":"3 : 3"},{"label":"6","y":5,"custom":"3 : 3"}];
 $.each(abc,function(i,el)
{
 dataPie.push({name :el.label,y: parseFloat(el.y)});

});
```

[See the working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ng1kvmxh/34/)

Comment: Thank you for reply but i want label : y in hover of the chart and outside of each block of chart.
Please reply.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you attach a mockup of your requested chart?